# Barplot Error in R using ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I try to make a barplot of a time-series dataset with `ggplot2` but I get following error message (I have performed this on a similar dataset and it works):

```
Error in if (!is.null(data$ymin) && !all(data$ymin == 0)) warning("Stacking not well defined when ymin != 0",  : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

For this I have used following code:

```
p <- ggplot(dataset, aes(x=date, y=value)) + geom_bar(stat="identity")
```

If I use `geom_point()` instead of `geom_bar()` it works fine.

Comment: You will have to provide us with a reproducible example.  There is possibly something odd about your data.  What is the smallest subset of `dataset` that will still reproduce this error?  Once you've identified this, please post the results of `dput(dataset[..subset.., ]` in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't provided a reproducible example, so I'm just guessing, but your syntax doesn't look right to me.  Check here: http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/geom_bar.html

Bar charts by default produce tabulations of counts:

```
p <- ggplot( dataset, aes( factor(date) ) ) + geom_bar()
```

If you want it to do something different, you'll need to tell it what statistic to use.  See the link above (towards the bottom) for an example using the mean.  Alternatively, see here for a hybrid point/scatterplot (very bottom of the page):
http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/position_jitter.html

But fundamentally you have two continuous variables and it's not clear to me why you'd want anything but a scatterplot.

Comment: I'm not sure your analysis is necessarily correct.  `stat="identity"` is a valid statistical summary in `ggplot` (i.e. don't summarise).

Comment: I only want bars instead of points. With a different dataset this works fine, but now I get the error message.

Comment: @pmuench There is possibly something odd about your data.  Please post your data in the original question, as I suggested, so we can have a look.

Comment: @pmuench: @Adrie is correct...there's something odd about your data relative to what you want to plot it as.  Please `dput(dataset)` and post the output here.

Comment: I have found the mistake. There was a entry with "NA" because of computation errors. If I remove the line it works. Thank you.